# How to track a file changes in c# .net 4.5

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program in c# that whenever someone tries to open a certain .exe file, let call it "prog.exe", The program will shut it down and randomly open one of three other programs, lets call them "a.exe", "b.exe", "c.exe". My problem is I don't want users to interrupt it simply by changing the file's name or location. Is there a way I can know if a file's name or location changed?

I have managed to do everything  from finding the program to kill, kill it using `.Kill()` and open randomly the needed .exe file by using

```
     Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
     int progNum = rand.Next(1, 3);
     string progName = "a.exe";

     switch (progNum)
     {
        case 2:
           progName = "b.exe";
           break;
        case 3:
           progName = "c.exe";
           break;
     }

     Process.Start(@"c:\" + progName);
```

but i couldn't quite figure out how to track changes to those files. for the time being, every minute, i have a search that going through the drive and search for the exe files if not found in the directory i want, but that's not enough, and a simple name change won't be noticed.

- is there any other way to do it?
- or a better way to track after files change?
- or even just keep a copy in the memory and save it to the hard drive
  if not found on the location needed?

Comment: I don't think this is the place? Just my opinion...

Comment: @Belogix for asking how to track a file in a program language? why? that an program question, not an ethical

Comment: What have you tried? You've basically just said I want to prank someone, how do I do it? No effort on your part. Have a go and when you get stuck ask but maybe do it in a way where people might not think you have negative intents.

Comment: I feel like if you make it too permanent/invasive, it wouldn't be very "fun" for the other person. It'd probably be best if you let it be easily defeatable... Just something that does getProcessByName("iexplore"). Yes, if he changes the file name, it may not work anymore... but this should be a temporary thing regardless. Installing stuff that permanently alters your co-workers workflow could be seen as hostile. Just my opinion.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher.Renamed Event should do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed.aspx

Comment: Done, new question looks much better.

Comment: @Gray i know it's been 2 months since your comment but iv'e edited the question so if you'll be so king to go through it and maybe remove the downvote

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Sorry, but I did not downvote, only wanted to make the comment. Actually, I have also just noticed that I don't think you can rename iexplore (due to Windows File Protection), so that solution is probably plenty robust.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ie = Process.GetProcesses()
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("iexplore"));

if (ie != null)
    ie.Kill();
```